# Find the minimum value of $\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x^2_i - i^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have $x_i >i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. 
Find the minimum value of $$\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x^2_i - i^2}}$$

any help guys please?

Answer (score 0):

$$(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2\geq(\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x^2_i - i^2})^2+(\sum_{i=1}^n i)^2\geq2(\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x^2_i - i^2})(\sum_{i=1}^n i),$$

$$\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x^2_i - i^2}}\geq n(n+1).$$

$(i=1,2,\cdots,n)$
So equality holds when $$x_i=\sqrt{2}i $$